# AngularGoogleMaps　以前表示したルートが残ったままになる

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

[AngularGoogleMaps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/)を使用して、出発地A,中継地B,目的地Cのルート表示を試みています。
しかし、以下の動作になり困っています。

1. Aを設定、Bを設定、Cを設定。実行→ルート表示される　（これはOK）
2. Bを変更、A・Cはそのまま。実行→ルート表示されるが、1で表示したルートも表示されたままになる（NG。1のルート軌跡は消えてほしい）

どなたか解決方法がわかる方、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

[plunkerにソース](http://plnkr.co/edit/GCXBPYIWp11jI9XC7q5Y?p=preview)を置いています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

servGoogleMaps.calcRoute()を呼ぶたびにDirectionsRendererを生成していることが原因です。

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

の宣言をcalcRouteの外に出して、`new google.maps.DirectionRenderer()`を一度だけ呼ぶようにすれば動きます。ついでに`new google.maps.DirectionsService()`の呼び出しも外に出したほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。DirectionsRendererで毎回ルートとマーカーの描画しているので、mapオブジェクトに実行したルートがすべて表示されたま‌​まになった、という認識でよろしいでしょうか？　DirectionsServiceで毎回DirectionsService（道案内サービス？）のオブジェクト生成をお‌​こなっているのは無駄にリソースを消費してしまいますね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: はい。calcRoute()のたびに新たにDirectionsRendererを作成してマップに追加するという操作を行っていたため、マップには作成した数だけのDirectionsRendererが表示されていたというわけです。